# Script to lock a different tab sheet everyday

Tags: google-sheets, time, range, locking, cell

So I made this spreadsheet with multiple sheets for every day of the month (1-31), there's a staff member that before closing the clinic (it's a medical clinic), every day, she types in what we made (debit, credit, cash, expenses). She only have access to the same certain ranges of every sheet; I locked every sheet with an exception to these ranges (the ones she can edit).

The thing is, when she comes back the next day of work and login in the spreadsheet she can still edit the previous days; What I have to do is to every night take out the cells exceptions for that day sheet, so she can't edit previous days after it has been passed.

Is there a script where I can set for everyday to automatically take out these ranges exceptions for certain sheets? Example:
01/01/24 20:00h lock sheet 1 with no range exceptions.
01/02/24 20:00h lock sheet 2 with no range exceptions.
01/03/24 20:00h lock sheet 2 with no range exceptions.
and so on until the 31.

The ranges I have **unlocked** (the ones the staff member can edit) from every sheets are:
(G5)/(G20:G23)/(A9:G17)/(G27)/(A47:G49)/(A33:G41)

The name of the sheets I would like the script to lock are:
"1" all the way to "31"

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Locking sheets is not an uncommon topic. Have you tried to write a script? Have you found any other answers that are similar to what you want to do?

Comment: I'm sorry but I find the question confusing; some sections seem inconsistent with others. May I try to clarify? You have a spreadsheet with 31 sheets (named 1-31): one sheet for each day of the month; a staff member uses the spreadsheet; after each day's trading, you want to lock the sheet for the previous day EXCEPT for some specific cells/ranges to be set as "unprotected"; the outcome is that the staff member can _view_ any sheet for a previous trading day but they cannot edit any cells on a previous trading sheet _except for specific unprotected cells/ranges_. Is this correct? Comments?

Comment: BTW, how do you plan to transition from January to February to March, etc

Comment: @Tedinoz I've tried looking for other posts to see if I could find an answer or maybe something that I could manipulate, but no luck. I don't know to write the it myself.

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes, I have a spreadsheet with 31 sheets (named 1-31), the staff member uses the spreadsheet, I add her email to the spreadsheet; in the end of each day, before we close the clinic (it's a medical clinic), she inputs in specific cells the amount we received in credit, debit, cash, etc. The entire spreadsheet is locked, but when I locked, I marked an exception for those ranges that I wrote in the post. Those are the ranges that she can edit, all the rest is locked. In the end of each day, after its all filled out, I take those cell exceptions out.... (continue in next comment)

Comment: @Tedinoz I take those exceptions out, so when we open the clinic the next day, and she login in the spreadsheet theres no way she can edit the amounts of previous days................. As for the transition for the next months, I do it manually, I added some scripts that clear all the inputed data by her and locks up all sheets with the range exceptions again. So I just duplicate she spreadsheet, and run the scripts to clear and start again. I do it every beginning of the month, just this daily part of taking the exceptions out that I forget a lot of times, a script would help a lot

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: @Tedinoz The spreadsheet will be used in Brasília time zone (UTC-3). I added your script and ran it to see if it would make an effect, but it gave me an error. I'm sorry, I am probably doing something wrong. I created a new spreadsheet and made it public, your script name is DailyLock.... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UlDwd_dtQ8RV9Zl5yLlfb1--xKgXo_dTCETU0tNpahk/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Tedinoz I was thinking here, I didnt know there was a command I could add in a function that would get the day of the month (day-of-month). So if I had 2 functions, one unlocking the "day-of-month" sheet; And another one locking the "day-of-month" sheet. And making 2 daily time-triggers, first one to unlock so it would unlock that day sheet and clear the exceptions; and the second time-trigger to run the lock function to lock that days sheet without any exceptions. Sorry, I know it seems confusing, I'm just having a hard time explaining in words. I dont know how to write the scripts at all

Comment: No, its not confusing - it makes sense but... it's a new topic that should be posted as a new question. On a tangent, learning scripts is something that you need to do. I agree that this is jumping in at the deep end, but StackOverflow exists to help _you_ solve problems, not to solve them for you.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hello my friend, sorry for the delay, I'm also a sailor and was offshore these last few weeks. No worries, you helped out a lot by giving the info you did. Thanks for the help, the community need ppl like you

Comment: So, where do we stand with this now, Miguel? When you installed the script, did you also add a time-driven trigger? I'm running the script against your spreadsheet and its not generating an error.

Comment: @Tedinoz I added the script and test ran it. It gives me the following error: "Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'day-of-month')
tradingDayUpdate @ DailyLock.gs:10" I'm now trying to understand the script to see if I can edit to make it work.

Comment: Have you created the installable time-driven trigger  (say, every one minute)? The function doesn’t run from the editor, it is started by the trigger. Plus you could uncomment the “logger” to display the value of ‘day-of-month’.

Comment: Ok, I got it working with the time-driven. I logged in with the employee username to see if it would lock the cells for her but it didnt. Making today as an example, now when I access the sheet Protect Settings, it shows "Protected Trading Day#28" on top and right on bottom still says "28 except 7 ranges". So, she still have the ability to edit these 7 Ranges. (in my timezone, im still on the 28th of january). I'm trying to find something similar on the internet to maybe use together with the function "day-of-month" that you showed me, Very little content I'm finding

Answer (score 0):

You have a spreadsheet with 31 sheets (named 1-31): one sheet for each day of the month; a staff member uses the spreadsheet; after each day's trading, you lock the spreadsheet EXCEPT for some specific cells/ranges set as "unprotected"; the outcome is that the staff member can *view* the sheet for the previous trading day but edit only those *specific unprotected cells/ranges*. You want a time-triggered function that will run late on thr evening of the trading day that will protect the trading day sheet and remove the specific unprotected cells.

Try this function.
Things to note:

- create an installable time-driven trigger for the function
- check that the editor timezone is consistent with the sheet timezone so that the `day-of-month` event object is accurate when the trigger runs.

---

**Logic**

- the function makes use of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven-events). Specifically the `day-of-month` event object.
- in a step that *could* be deleted, JavaCcript [indexOf] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is used to find a match within the list of sheet names.

---

```
function tradingDayUpdate(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  // list of trading day sheets
  var sheetNames = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // get the Event Object for the day of the month
  var dayOfMonth = e['day-of-month']
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: The day of the month: "+dayOfMonth)

  // find the index matching the day of the month
  var dayMatch = sheetNames.indexOf(dayOfMonth) // zero-based
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: dayMatch = "+dayMatch)
  // get the actual SheetNumber
  var sheetName = sheetNames[dayMatch] 
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Trading Day sheet number = "+sheetName)

  // get the sheet and activate (make it the Activesheet)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.activate();
  // Protect the active sheet, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription("Protected Trading Day#"+sheetName);

  // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
  // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  // Gets the description of the protected sheet and logs it to the console.
  var sampleProtectedSheetDescription = protection.getDescription();
  // Logger.log(""+sampleProtectedSheetDescription);
  
}
```